# Find the greatest $x$ that divides 14, 19, 25, 52 and leaves remainders 4, 1, 5 and 2, respectively

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

Given a question as follows.

> Find the greatest $x$ that divides 14, 19, 25, 52 and leaves remainders 4, 1, 5 and 2, respectively.

For me this question does not make sense. Because the $\text{HCF}$ of $14-4$, $19-1$, $25-5$, and $52-2$ is $\text{HCF}(10,18,20,50)=2$.

Here if $x=2$ then it divides 14 without remainder. But the question said its remainder is 4. Or I am wrong?

## Question

How to properly explain that this question does not make sense?

Comment: You're correct. Why do you think the question doesn't make sense?

Comment: @LukasKofler: 2 divides 14 without remainder.

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer It could: $14 = 5\cdot 2 + 4$. Depending on how your problem author meant "leaves remainder". It's not standard, but it's conceivable.

Comment: @Arthur So, the question could be rephrased as $14\equiv4\pmod{x}$ and so forth?

Comment: You are right $-$ the question makes no sense.

Comment: @saulspatz That seems like a much more sensible way to phase the question (the way I read it, at least).

Comment: The only numbers that divide 14 with a remainder of 4 are 5 and 10. They do not satisfy the other conditions, so there is no solution.